Java static members of abstract classes
I have following setup: superclass Vehicle with atribute capacity and two subclasses Bus and Tram. All trams have the same capacity as well as all buses (it should be static attribute), but capacity of a tram may be different from capacity of a bus. How to implement such approach in Java?
I have partially solved the problem just ignoring the fact that capacity should be static attribute for all subclasses (no static attributes).

Encapsulate the capacity in a method getCapacity. That method can look for a TRAM_CAPACITY or BUS_CAPACITY static variable depending on which class is implementing it. This way you don't need to care about static variables and inheritance.

Agreed.  Exposing mutable state via attributes rather than getters (and setters) is a bad idea anyway.  And in this case, you can use the getter and over-riding to resolve to the correct static field.

In the real world you wouldn't have these derived classes. You would have a Vehicle class with a type attribute, which in turn would have a capacity attribute, via a process akin to database 3NF. This is overworking OO in a direction that looks obvious but turns out to be futile in practice.

Does this answer your question? What is the best practice in Java to set a constant required in subclasses? It may not be exactly the same question, but I still think the answer given there may be useful.

You should encapsulate the capacity in a getCapacity method. That method can then look for an appropriate static variable for the specific class, so for example:
abstract class Vehicle {
    public int getCapacity();
}

class Tram {

    private static final int TRAM_CAPACITY = 200;

    @Override
    public int getCapacity() {
        return TRAM_CAPACITY;
    }
}

class Bus {

    private static final int BUS_CAPACITY = 100;

    @Override
    public int getCapacity() {
        return BUS_CAPACITY;
    }
}

This has the added bonus that if one day you want to calculate the capacity based on some other property (for example the number of seats on a tram given a single cart capacity multiplied by the number of carts) you can modify getCapacity directly without modifying the client code.
class Tram {

    private static final int CART_CAPACITY = 100;

    private int carts;

    public Tram(int carts) { this.carts = carts; }

    @Override
    public int getCapacity() {
        return CART_CAPACITY * carts;
    }
}


Make capacity assignable only through Vehicle constructor, and have inheritors supply their predefined value - do not expose it through their constructors.
public abstract class Vehicle {

  private final int capacity;

  protected Vehicle(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
  }

  //maybe a getter for capacity?
  //or use it in other methods as needed
}

For this example in particular inheritor constructor is no-args, but it can set Bus specific attributes, other from capacity, if needed.
public class Bus extends Vehicle {

  //every bus has the same capacity - 50
  private static final int BUS_CAPACITY = 50;

  public Bus() {
    super(BUS_CAPACITY);
  }
  
  //other bus specific stuff
}

